# How scoping is handled in exceptions

Tags: exception, scope

How is the scoping of variables handled during exceptions? I suppose this will be language specific, and answers for any specific language are greatly appreciated. At least maybe the big ones? `C++, python, Java`. This is what I mean:

**python**

```
        try:
            for k, v in map.iteritems():
                cnf.conf.set( section, k, v )
            for i, j in map2.iteritems():
                dosomethingelse()
                for m in range(10):
                    morestuff()
        except SpecificError:
            vars = (k, v, i, j, m)
        finally:
            vars in scope #?
```

Or something more complicated, like nested blocks:

```
    try:
        try:
            for k, v in map.iteritems():
                cnf.conf.set( section, k, v )
            for i, j in map2.iteritems():
                dosomethingelse()
                for m in range(10):
                    morestuff()
        except SpecificError:
            vars = (k, v, i, j, m)
    except:
        vars in scope #?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, I believe you can *not* do the following:

```
try {
 String s = "Hello, finally!";
 ...
}
finally {
 System.out.println(s);
}
```

You must instead do:

```
String s = null;

try {
 s = "Hello, finally!";
 ...
}
finally {
 System.out.println(s);
}
```

In other words, the scope of the variable is limited to the block in which it is defined.

HTH